# Csv file with first row as keys

Tags: python, csv

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong
I assigned the dictionary key (mydict) to the first column
With the command:

```
print(mydict.get('000000'))
```

I wanted to have the ouput of the REGISTRATION value connected with DEVICE_ID.

Example:

```
print(mydict.get('000000'))
```

output

```
OK-7777
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time and I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Code:

```
import csv

if __name__=="__main__":
    mydict = {}
    reader = csv.reader(open("aerei.csv", "r"))
    for rows in reader:
        k = rows[0]
        v = rows[1]
        mydict[k] = v

        print(mydict.get('000000'))

#print (mydict)
```

aerei.csv

```
"DEVICE_ID","REGISTRATION"
"'000000'","'OK-7777'"
"'000001'","''"
"'000002'","'OY-XRG'"
```

Comment: `dict.get` doesn't assign values, it retrieves them

Answer (score 3):

It seems your `print` command is inside the for-loop, so it didn't finish reading all entries yet.

Also your csv file seems to have quotes inside quotes, so you want to remove them:

```
for rows in reader:
    k = rows[0].strip('"\'')
    v = rows[1].strip('"\'')
    mydict[k] = v
print(mydict.get('000000'))
```